# How do I make the title blank disappear for a highchart spider chart?

Tags: highcharts

For example:

https://jsfiddle.net/zvj2nmyk/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    chart: {
        polar: true,
        type: 'line'
    },

    title: {
        text:null // Already hide this but still occupy a lot of space at the top of my chart
    },
...
}
```

In this code I have removed the title part of the chart but the chart is still having a lot of blank space at the top.

How do I remove the top space?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The blank space isn't from the title but from `pane` and `legend`. This options will change the render:

```
pane: {
  // size: '60%'
},
legend: {
  enabled:false,
},
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/core972/90h8zjoq/1/)

Comment: In your fiddle, the top space didn't change. Only the right-padding removed.

Comment: Remove `pane:{size:60%}`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fzduqmrn/ If I change the width to a smaller number, there are still a lot of unwanted space (at both top and below). Please take a look.

Comment: Of course there is lot of space cause Highcharts will make sure ALL the chart appear in the container, that how it works.